# Autofill space up to fixed Column width on each line

Tags: text, edit, fixed-width, emeditor

I am trying to set the column width of each line to a fixed "511" width on a large dataset. If the line has less than 511 column width then I want to add space on the end of the line until it has 511 column width. Currently, I am running into a lot of the entries that have irregular column widths. For instance, if the column width is 450 i.e. less than than 511 then I am manually adding space until it has 511 width and if column width exceeds 511 then I am deleting space until it is 511. The current dataset has over 1 million rows so I was wondering if there was faster way to add "spaces" on the end of each line. Would appreciate any help.

[Sample of irregular column width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMz1S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there aren't many irregular lines (if most lines are 511 characters long), you can use this macro.  Otherwise, this macro might take a long time to finish.

```
COLUMN = 511 + 1;  // add 1 to the width
Redraw = false;
nLines = document.GetLines();
for( y = 1; y <= nLines; ++y ) {
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, y );
    document.selection.EndOfLine( false, eeLineLogical );
    x = document.selection.GetActivePointX( eePosLogical );
    if( x < COLUMN ) {
        s = "";
        for( i = COLUMN - x ; i > 0; --i ) {
            s += " ";
        }
        document.selection.Text = s;
    }
    else if( x > COLUMN ) {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, COLUMN, y, true );
        document.selection.Delete();
    }
}
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `AutoSpace.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run AutoSpace.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

Comment: Thank you for macro, I will try it out and get back to you Yutaka

Comment: Just tried it. It works thanks very much!!